# force htaccess to rewrite url from last slash

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, slash

I need to use htaccess to change below url:

```
http://example.com/main/en/index.php?page=pages&page_id=9
```

to:

```
http://example.com/main/en/pages/9.html
```

I've done it by the below rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /main/fa/?index.php?page=$1&page_id=$2 [L]
```

but there is a problem, this rule make my display url to:

```
http://example.com/pages/9.html
```

I want to htaccess change url just after last slash.

Because I must have more than one language, it will have conflict with other languages. How must I write this rule?

Comment: @Kees ¿Shouldn't be the code as `code`, not in `bold`?

Comment: i'm new, from next one i'll consider this, thank you.

Comment: @faa it's hard to say if this is really code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([\d]+)\.html/?   [NC]
RewriteRule  .*          main/%1/index.php?page=%2&page_id=%3 [L]
```

Will redirect internally:

`http://example.com/main/LangCode/PageName/PageID.html`

To:

`http://example.com/main/LangCode/index.php?page=PageName&page_id=PageID`

Comment: thank you, now its just remove the "/main" but its so better :)